# Javascript - Three.js material and shadow

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I was wondering what I did wrong with choosing mesh material. As you see:
[image]

The black ones looks fine the shadow is smooth and correct. However, if you notice, the white ones look strange and the shadow, in my opinion, its not perfect. (very noticeable on HORSE)

For black one I used- `MeshPhongMaterial`, for the white ones - `MeshBasicMaterial`. Strange things happens if I try to change `MeshBasicMaterial` into `MeshPhongMaterial` or `MeshLambertMaterial`, my white figures become black.

Here is a source code: https://fiddle.jshell.net/m4tv0s3p/

Very similar issue : [ThreeJS shadow not rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536903/threejs-shadow-not-rendering)

Maybe someone can suggest a solution? or workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `renderer` you are missing:

```
renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
```

and on the `light` you should add:

```
spotLight.shadowMapWidth = 2048;
spotLight.shadowMapHeight = 2048;
```

These are for the version of three.js you are using (r60) which is pretty old.